# How to change the text of a Button in a fragment in Android

Tags: android

I need to change the `text of a button` according to certain conditions, but this within a `Fragment`, but when I try to do I have an error here:
    mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);
someone could tell me how to correct this.
Here is my code:

```
private boolean mConfigModeConsola;
private String modoConsola = "";

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

mSendText = view.findViewById(R.id.send_text);
mHexBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hex_btn);

mHexBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mConfigModeConsola == false) {
            mConfigModeConsola = true;,
            modoConsola = "HEX";
            mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);.
            mSendText.setText( "." );
         }
        else {
            mConfigModeConsola = false;
            modoConsola = "ASCIII";
            mHexBtn.setText(modoConsolas);
            mSendText.setText( "" );
        }
    }
});

return view;
}
```

Here the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN5N5.png)

Comment: Can you pleas show the definition of the variable `mHexBtn`?

Comment: Are you 100% sure mHexBtn is an instance of the Button class?

Comment: i see a bug in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure few things before you proceed.

1. Make sure that mHexBtn is an object of `Button` class.
2. Your Android Studio is updated, and if it's not, you're typecasting findViewById(R.id.mHexBtn) to `Button`.

   Button mHexBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mHexBtn);

If you've confirmed above things, then your code is correct, then,

1. Try rebuilding the project.

> Build -> Rebuild Project

2. If it doesn't work, try,

> Build-> Clean Project

3. And if clean project doesn't work, try,

> File-> Invalidate caches/Restart

Android Studio bugs out like that sometimes.